# Create data dump in Excel pulling data from Website

Tags: excel, web, extract

I am looking to pull college football team stats from www.cfbstats.com.  The teams are listed on the left panel and clicking into them will take you to the team's season statistics.  I want to pull part of these statistics into Excel so I do not have to manually do this for each team every week.

Can anyone assist in how I would do this, or what the best way to approach would be?

Thanks

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Understood.  So the biggest problem is I know minimal code most of which is just through doing exercises on Codecademy.  I am happy to do the leg work, but at this stage I do not know the code or language that would get this done or where to even start.  Maybe the better question is where is a place to start to find out this information?

Comment: Start by using the build in excel Macro Recorder. This will built a macro the simulates *most* things you do in your worksheet and generate the code to replicate the steps in a new macro. These ARE terribly ineeficiant and add many addition steps to the final code ***BUT*** they are probably the number one way to get started and you learn alot very fast. Also if you are trying to get information from the web look into using a Web Query, I will add an answer showing you how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can pull data from some websites using the built in excel qwb query tool, a quick test looks like it should work very well for the data you are trying to collect. Follow these steps.

I would start with having a new Worksheet for each team you would like to pull the stats in for, obviously name them correspondingly

Then Goto the Data Tab and select From Web (this is in 2007, but while maybe SLIGHTLY different in other version it will be inside that tab.)

[image]

In the Address bar enter your website and select the team from the links on the Left of the page the correspondes with the current sheet you are on (I will just use the first team for this example)

[image]

After that notice the little yellow box with an arrow next to the table with the stats, this is telling you that you can pull in that data, just click on the box and excel will select yo import all of the information for you, Then just click  the import button:

[image]

You will get an Import Range box just select where you want the table to be (I used the first cell of the Sheet A1) and all your data will be in the worksheet:

[image]

***NOTES:*** You can refresh this data manually whenever you feel by right clicking any part of the information and selecting Refresh from the menu. You may also goto DataRange Properties and tell it to refresh and specific intervals (every 5,10,60 minutes or the like). Also is an option to have the table pull in the data when you open the worksheet (also inside the properies window.)

Hope this works for your needs!! Cheers!